# How write singleton class stuff in SWIFT 3.0

Tags: swift

How write singleton class setup in swift 3.0. Currently i am using this code in objective c .
 How write singleton class setup in swift 3.0. Currently i am using this code in objective c

```
 #pragma mark Singleton
static ModelManager* _instance = nil;

+ (ModelManager *) sharedInstance {
@synchronized([ModelManager class]){
    if (!_instance) {
        _instance = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return _instance;
}
return nil;
}
+ (id)alloc {
@synchronized([ModelManager class]){

    NSAssert(_instance == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
    _instance = [super alloc];
    return _instance;
}
return nil;
}
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
@synchronized([CTEModelManager class]) {
    NSAssert(_instance == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
    _instance= [super allocWithZone:zone];
    return _instance; // assignment and return on first allocation
}
return nil; //on subsequent allocation attempts return nil
}
- (id)init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
}
return self;
}
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
return self;
}
```

Comment: There is also a "Singleton" section in [Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6).

Answer (score 2):

Apple finally took care of that, it's this simple ...

```
open class Grid {
    static let shared = Grid()
```

As a rule (you can google endless discussion on this), you add

```
open class Grid {
    static let shared = Grid()
    fileprivate init() {}
```

That's all there is to it.

To use the singleton you simply "Name.shared", so

```
 x = Grid.shared.someFunction()
```

---

## The "pure sugar" idiom...

Consider this: [Any reason not use use a singleton "variable" in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32660471/294884) addition.  Be aware it is pure syntactic sugar, or perhaps cocaine, and may or may not be right for you.

Comment: class SingletonClass: NSObject
    {
       static let sharedInstance = SingletonClass()
        
        func isValidEmail(_ testStr:String) -> Bool
        {
           let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
           let range = testStr.range(of: emailRegEx, options:.regularExpression)
          let result = range != nil ? true : false
          return result
       }
    }

Comment: hi @VibhaSingh.  you need to ask a new, separate question for that.  Cheers.