# Global var vs Shared Instance swift

Tags: swift, instance, global

What is the difference between global variable and shared instance in Swift? what are their respective field of use? Could anyone clarify their concept based upon Swift.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660471/any-reason-not-use-use-a-singleton-variable-in-swift

Answer (score 10):

A global variable is a variable that is declared at the top level in a file. So if we had a class called `Bar`, you could store a reference to an instance of `Bar` in a global variable like this:

```
var bar = Bar()
```

You would then be able to access the instance from anywhere, like this:

```
bar
bar.foo()
```

A shared instance, or singleton, looks like this:

```
class Bar {
    static var shared = Bar()
    private init() {}
    func foo() {}
}
```

Then you can access the shared instance, still from anywhere in the module, like this:

```
Bar.shared
Bar.shared.foo()
```

However, one of the most important differences between the two (apart from the fact that global variables are just generally discouraged) is that the singleton pattern restricts you from creating other instances of `Bar`. In the first example, you could just create more global variables:

```
var bar2 = Bar()
var bar3 = Bar()
```

However, using a singleton (shared instance), the initialiser is private, so trying to do this...

```
var baaar = Bar()
```

...results in this:

> 'Bar' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

That's a good thing, because the point of a singleton is that there is a *single* shared instance. Now the only way you can access an instance of `Bar` is through `Bar.shared`. It's important to remember to add the `private init()` in the class, and not add any other initialisers, though, or that won't any longer be enforced.

If you want more information about this, there's a great article by KrakenDev [here](https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton).

Comment: In `Swift` you can declare `init` `fileprivate` and put declaration of global variable into the same file, and described difference is gone. You have `global variable` and can't create any more instances of the type, because `init` is inaccessible.

Comment: That's true, that's another option. As far as I know, though, what I described is the typical pattern for a singleton or shared instance in Swift.

Answer (score -2):

**Singleton** (sharing instance)

Ensure that only one instance of a singleton object is created & It's provide a globally accessible through shared instance of an object that could be shared even across an app.
The dispatch_once function, which executes a block once and `only once for the lifetime of an app`.

**Global variable**

Apple documentation says Global variables are variables that are defined `outside of any function, method, closure, or type context`.

Comment: Those aren't global variables. You quoted the documentation saying that global variables are defined outside of any type context, and then declared your "global variables" within types.