# In Swift what's the difference between a singleton and a global let variable?

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift we can have a global `let` variable initialized once and available everywhere.

```
let container = Container()
class Container {

}
```

Or the standard `Singleton` pattern like:

```
class Container {
   static var instance = Container()
}
```

Since both are initialized once, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939952/global-var-vs-shared-instance-swift

Comment: Your second example doesn't protect the initializer by making it `private`. It's *not* a singleton.