# Singletons in Swift 5

Tags: ios, singleton, swift5

Here's precisely how I make a singleton,

```
public class Model
    {
    static let shared = Model()
    // For ocd friends. Add this line: private init() {}
    
    func test() -> Double
        {
        return 3.33
        }
    }
```

then elsewhere...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
    {
    override func viewDidLoad()
        {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Holy singleton test, Batman! \( Model.shared.test() )")
        }
    }
```

What about in Swift 5?

Any new dramas or insights?  Have they perhaps added "actual" singletons, or?

Comment: Is there any reason you'd expect a change in Swift 5? Changing the nature of `static` would see extreme at the least. The whole point of the current system is that there's no magic at all. It's not even a singleton. There's just one easily accessible instance (and w/ `private`, it is difficult to make other instances). This question feels like the start of an unbounded list of "has Swift5 changed `if`? No. Has Swift5 changed assignments? No. Has Swift5 changed closure syntax? No." Is there something special about singletons?

Comment: (yeah, finally finished…)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the idiom change you're describing. Swift has never really had "singletons" any more than ObjC (actually, less than ObjC). It's had shared instances, and the idiom for that has been the same since Swift 1 (and identical after transliteration to ObjC) as best I know.

Comment: @RobNapier - We actually had to contorted ourselves a bit to achieve singletons prior to Swift 1.2. But I agree that it’s a curious question to suddenly ask now, four years later.

Comment: @Rob I ignore all things before 1.2. They don't exist. (OK, maybe they do exist, but I reject them.)

Comment: @RobNapier He's probably referring to `dispatch_once` which existed in Swift 1 but then got hosed.

Comment: Sure - things changed once, they could change again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing new. It remains the same in Swift 5.